# Storing data for multiple categories?

Tags: mysql

Quick question think I think I know the answer to but in the back of my head there's a voice asking, "Why not do it this way?!"

So I'm working on something (for a bit of fun more than anything else) and I need to store lists of related items, like a list of balls, a list of blocks, a list of fish.. And so on, each of these items has an ID, NAME, DETAIL (maybe an path to an image).

They way I initially assumed I should do this was with two tables.

One being a table of categories like so:

```
CAT_ID | CAT_NAME
1      | BALLS
2      | BLOCKS
3      | FISH
```

And a table of all the items together where the CAT_ID would relate to the ID in the above table.

```
ITEM_ID | ITEM_CAT_ID | ITEM_NAME    | ITEM_DETAIL
1       | 1           | Soccer Ball  | A ball used in the game of Soccer
2       | 1           | Rugby Ball   | A ball used in the game of Rugby
3       | 3           | Trout        | A fresh-water fish
```

So on and so on.. But I wonder, is that a better method than making a table for each category and selecting from that table rather than 'where CAT_ID = #'?

I know it'll work either way, but what would be the proper/standard way of doing this?

The reason I thought the first way is because all items are going to have the same fields, might as well use the same table. But, am I wrong?

Comment: If you know that the columns are the same then 1 table is preferable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is fine. The main thing to notice is that by putting category in its own table you are helping to avoid insertion and deletion anomalies. Let's say your table was like this:

```
ITEM_ID | ITEM_CAT    | ITEM_NAME    | ITEM_DETAIL
1       | Balls       | Soccer Ball  | A ball used in the game of Soccer
2       | Balls       | Rugby Ball   | A ball used in the game of Rugby
3       | Fish        | Trout        | A fresh-water fish
```

Suddenly, I have no record of a `blocks` category existing and I won't until I add an item with that category. Likewise, I could make a typo and change item 2 to 'blals' and now if I query for all items with category `balls` I won't get a proper value. I'm sure you can see other possible anomalies.

---

In terms of normalization, in this specific example, using cat_name instead of cat_id in one table would still be in at least the third normal form because every non key column depends on the key. However, the situation may arise where you want to keep a category description also. In one table, you would have this:

```
item_id | cat_name | cat_description | item_name | item_detail
```

Now you have a transitive functional dependency, item_id -> cat_name and cat_name -> cat_description. Because of the transitive functional dependency, this table is only in second normal form.

If you're not familiar with the various normal forms, I actually found [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) helpful when I learned it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only a few categories and you know them all then yes you can put them one per table. But if you think e.g. of the categories of a blog: they might be hundreds and most important you don't know which they are. So you're forced to use two tables and the foreign key